# JQ: Delete JSON object with duplicates in nested array

Tags: nested, duplicates, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
[
{
  "ratings" : {
    "q1" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "a", "a", "a" ],
      "top_answer" : "a"
    },
    "q2" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "no", "yes", "yes" ],
      "top_answer" : "yes"
    }
},
{
  "ratings" : {
    "q1" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "a", "b", "b" ],
      "top_answer" : "a"
    },
    "q2" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "no", "yes", "yes" ],
      "top_answer" : "yes"
    }
},
{
  "ratings" : {
    "q1" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "a", "b", "c" ],
      "top_answer" : "a"
    },
    "q2" : {
      "all_answers" : [ "no", "yes", "yes" ],
      "top_answer" : "yes"
    }
},
{
...
}
]
```

I am attempting to create a jq script that can identify, if the array "all_answers" in q1 has duplicate entries and delete the entire object. In the end I want to only keep entries in the top level array .[] that have at least one divergent entry in .ratings.q1.all_answers.

My approach was to calculates the length of the array after removing duplicates and than compare it to the original length.

`jq '.[] |= select(.ratings.q1.all_answers | length as $len | $len > ($len - (. | unique | length)))'`

I don't get an error executing this but it does not seem to have any effect on the json. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> In my example I want to delete .[0] because all three values of q1 are the same ("all_answers" : [ "a", "a", "a" ]). There should be at least one different "answer" like [ "a", "b", "b" ] for it to stay

If you want that there is at least one pair of items with different values, then check if the length of the `unique` array is greater than `1`:

```bash
.[] |= select(.ratings.q1.all_answers | unique | length > 1)
```

```json
[
  {
    "ratings": {
      "q1": {
        "all_answers": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "b"
        ],
        "top_answer": "a"
      },
      "q2": {
        "all_answers": [
          "no",
          "yes",
          "yes"
        ],
        "top_answer": "yes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "ratings": {
      "q1": {
        "all_answers": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ],
        "top_answer": "a"
      },
      "q2": {
        "all_answers": [
          "no",
          "yes",
          "yes"
        ],
        "top_answer": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_6MPi3gk3AX)

Comment: sorry for not being clear. In my example I want to delete .[0] because all three values of q1 are the same ("all_answers" : [ "a", "a", "a" ]). There should be at least one different "answer" like [ "a", "b", "b" ] for it to stay

Comment: Then checking for `unique | length > 1` should suffice.

Comment: … You could also check if the unique array has a second element (at 0-based index 1): `unique | has(1)`; or just try to access that item (if it is guaranteed not to be `false` or `null`): `unique[1]`; or just check if the lowest and the highest value are different: `min != max`; …

Comment: yes, of course... Sorry, sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees... Thank you very much